# Generate PDF from HTML/CSS code with margins to all pages

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I need to convert an HTML page with a length that can vary to a PDF using JavaScript. I tried using multiple methods, like [Window.print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print), [jsPDF](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html) or [html-to-pdf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf-js). But I always ended up having the same problem: When the content was too large to fit in a page, a new one would be generated without any margin between the pages.

Here's an example of what I have been trying:

```
var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
doc.html(document.body, {
    callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save();
    },
});
```

And the undesired result:

[image: PDF without margins]

Comment: Your best bet is to have a search into doing something like: 1. create an iframe, 2. add what you want to print in the iframe, 3. window.print the iframe. That jsPDF library is a typesetter and will not convert bulk html. You are expected to only create lines, not paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up on using a JS framework and switched to using the [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) PHP framework, that has, between many other, the very useful option [`SetMargins()`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_setMargins):

```
require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML("<b>Bold text!</b>");
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```